# Springboot webscoket with external broker, dependency issues

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to make Websocket with stomp work with external message broker and it seems there are broken dependencies on reactor libraries.
Below is the exception that I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/publisher/Mono
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at chat.ChatApplication.main(ChatApplication.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/publisher/Mono
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at chat.ChatApplication.main(ChatApplication.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/publisher/Mono
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.startInternal(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:402)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.start(AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
```

POM FILE:

```
org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.0.2.RELEASE

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectreactor/reactor-net -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.22.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried this with other Spring boot versions starting from 1.5.x release but with lot of permutation with reactor version as well, but some error or the other.
Can you please help me with correct dependencies.